# How to handle controller dependecies in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am trying to write the test for my index controller, but I see that I need to pass the dependencies to it to be able to test its behavior, i applied the SOLID principles so I always instance the controllers using a dependency injection container, so I can do the same to instance the controller in the test file.

The question that is burning my head is whether or not that solution is correct because I understand that the point of the Unit Testing is to test the classes independently, and if I use the dependency container I'm are already putting another entity in game .. I mean , if the dependency container fails, then all my controller tests will fail too, without meaning that the controllers are doing their job wrong, then what would be the right solution?

```
<?php namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

use App\Controller\indexController;
use App\Controller\DependencyInjection;

class indexControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIndexControllerCheckIfReturnedCorrectHttpResponseCode ()
    {
        $controller = DependencyInjection::getInstance(indexController::class );

        $httpResponse = indexController()->index();

        return assertEqual( $httpResponse->getStatusCode(), 200 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create controller instance by yourself and inject dependencies into constructor as mocked objects.
That was only controller would have real instance and no other real methods (like DependencyInjection:getInstance) would be called.

You should have separate unit test for DependencyInjection class as well.